# mysql query building to get 2 different data from single column

Tags: mysql

Guys i m having a table in which i have gender and date columns as described.
now i wan to count both male n females registered in particular month,so how can i make my query for that.

```
mysql> select id,gender,entrydate from patient_master;

+----+--------+------------+
| id | gender | entrydate  |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | Male   | 2012-07-02 |
|  2 | Female | 2012-05-10 |
|  3 | Male   | 2012-05-25 |
|  4 | Female | 2012-07-09 |
|  5 | Male   | 2012-07-10 |
|  6 | Female | 2012-07-10 |
|  7 | Male   | 2012-07-10 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Comment: guys like from above example i want no of gender registered in month of may..so result will show count 1 for both male and female in same way it will show count 2 for both male and female for month of July

Comment: guys i need it for multiseries line graphs..so i guess i need data in such a way so that i can plot it for all months of a year.

Comment: What shape should the result set be? How many rows? 12? 24? How many columns? 3?

Comment: 24 rows(male and female) and 2 columns=gender and month

Comment: What about a column for the count?

Comment: yups sorry forgot that main thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results for all months:

```
SELECT YEAR(entrydate) AS yr, MONTH(entrydate) AS mnth, gender, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM patient_master
GROUP BY YEAR(entrydate), MONTH(entrydate), gender
```

If you want it for all months of a single year:

```
SELECT MONTH(entrydate) AS mnth, gender, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM patient_master
WHERE YEAR(entrydate) = 2012
GROUP BY MONTH(entrydate), gender
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select gender, count(id) as`count` 
from patient_master
where month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2012
group by gender
```

Month `1` = January, `2` = February...

Comment: So, for may, just change `month(entrydate) = 1` to `month(entrydate) = 5`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    date_format(entrydate,'%Y-%m-%b') YearMonth,
    gender,COUNT(1) GenderCount
FROM
    patient_master
GROUP BY
    date_format(entrydate,'%Y-%m-%b'),gender
;
```

Here is your sample data

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE patient_master
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     gender varchar(10),
    ->     entrydate date,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO patient_master (gender,entrydate) VALUES
    -> ('Male'  ,'2012-07-02'),
    -> ('Female','2012-05-10'),
    -> ('Male'  ,'2012-05-25'),
    -> ('Female','2012-07-09'),
    -> ('Male'  ,'2012-07-10'),
    -> ('Female','2012-07-10'),
    -> ('Male'  ,'2012-07-10');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Here is the output

```
mysql>     SELECT
    ->         date_format(entrydate,'%Y-%m-%b') YearMonth,
    ->         gender,COUNT(1) GenderCount
    ->     FROM
    ->         patient_master
    ->     GROUP BY
    ->         date_format(entrydate,'%Y-%m-%b'),gender
    ->     ;
+-------------+--------+-------------+
| YearMonth   | gender | GenderCount |
+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 2012-05-May | Female |           1 |
| 2012-05-May | Male   |           1 |
| 2012-07-Jul | Female |           2 |
| 2012-07-Jul | Male   |           3 |
+-------------+--------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

@juergen_d is right.

His query would return this:

```
+--------+--------+
| gender | count  |
+--------+--------+
| Male   |  1     |
| Female |  1     |
+--------+--------+
```